# No route to host error when using requests.post in python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send post request to URL from raspberry pi but I am getting Errno 113: No route to host error.
My code is:

```
import requests
>>> r = requests.post("http://alnnovative.com/security.php", data="marium")
```

I created a stack trace log file which I have uploaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xeomg3vrnxnmz0b/log.txt?dl=0
Can someone figure out the issue?